# CSV module to concatenate fields

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to concatenate some fields in 2 csv files. Normally this task is easily done in Excel using index match, however, I would like to do it in Python.

CSV A (has 3 columns)

```
ID, Age, FirstName
1,   18,   Lia
2,   18,   Joe
2,   18,   John
```

CSV B (has 3 columns)

```
ID, Gender, 
1,    Female,  
2,    Male,
```

CSV C (I want to create this)

```
ID, Age, FirstName, Gender
1,   18,   Lia,     Female
2,   18,   Joe,     Male
2,   18,   John,    Male
```

How can I achieve this using Python's csv module?

Comment: Does this have to be done with the CSV module, or would you be open to using another module such as Pandas?

Comment: @pythonicwiz it would be pretty trivial to do this with Pandas. The csv module in Python has methods for reading and writing to csv files -- it does not have an interface for joining or merging csv files. A tool like Pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/getting_started.html), which can read a csv and write a csv, but also has powerful join features, would help. Or an ETL library like pyetl (https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io.html)

Comment: @ChrisOram Yes I am trying to familiarise myself with the csv Module!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying that the solution must be done using the [built in CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or a specific tool, you should consider why.

From the docs:

> The csv module implements classes to read and write tabular data in CSV format...
> The csv module’s reader and writer objects read and write sequences. Programmers can also read and write data in dictionary form using the DictReader and DictWriter classes.

This doesn't sound like this fits in with this use case of merging CSVs.
If this is done to familiarise yourself with the csv module alone, then consider choosing another use case to work on.

---

To elaborate on this point and answer the question with the specified criteria, I have done it in two ways:

1. Forced solution using CSV module

Assuming CSV A -> one.csv and CSV B -> two.csv and CSV C -> out.csv

```py
import csv

def get_csv_lines(filename):
    """Read csv using csv.DictReader and return 
    the lines as a list of dictionaries."""
    lines = []
    with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in csv_reader:
            lines.append(row)
    return lines

def write_csv_lines(filename, lines):
    """Take a list of dictionaries and write to CSV file.
    Keys are headers, values are row values."""
    with open(filename, mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = lines[0].keys()
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for line in lines:
            writer.writerow(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l1 = get_csv_lines('one.csv')
    l2 = get_csv_lines('two.csv')
    l3 = []
    for num, dic1 in enumerate(l1):  # foreign key first
        l3.append(dic1)
        for dic2 in l2:  # primary key second
            if dic1['ID'] == dic2['ID']:
                l3[num].update(dic2)  # cannot guarantee order so would have to do some more trickery if needed
    write_csv_lines('out.csv', l3)
```

This is also based on this specific use case where one csv has a foreign key of ID and the other csv has a primary key of ID.

2. The ease of Pandas library

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('one.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('two.csv')
df3 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, how='inner', on='ID')
df3.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Exactly the use case Pandas merge method was built for.